# Google Data Analytics Citibike, Work with Subqueries

Tags: google-bigquery, subquery

I was trying to figure this out for ages taking the Google Data Analytics course, and I realized that the instructor puts in bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations INSTEAD OF bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations

Since new_york is not a dataset, I am still confused about that part and appreciate any suggestions on how this works when new_york is not a dataset. However, station_id is a STRING and start_station_id is an INT, so I did a SAFE_CAST as was suggested elsewhere for working in BigQuery instead of just CAST. None of that was in the course, so perhaps the dataset has changed since the course was made.

The following worked for me and returned the station_id and name for 'Subscribers'. Hopefully that can help others who are stuck on this one and were following the instructor line-by-line with no luck.

```
SELECT 
  station_id,
  name
FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_stations
WHERE station_id
  IN
    ((SELECT SAFE_CAST(start_station_id AS STRING) 
    FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips
    WHERE usertype= 'Subscriber'))
```

This was what I first put in, and it kept giving me an error. When I first did the CAST, it returned a "No data returned" message...

```
SELECT
    station_id, name
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations`
  WHERE station_id IN 
    (SELECT start_station_id
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
        WHERE usertype = 'Subscriber')
```